# Python Flask Sqlite fetch my query problem

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I am trying to execute a query to my sqlite db with:

```
import sqlite3
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        #print(sqlite3.version)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

db = create_connection("C:/Users/afonso.pinto/OneDrive - Unipartner IT Services, S.A/Documents/Faculdade/Tese - db e código/tweets.sqlite3")
c = db.cursor()
data={}


#Obter dados da BD
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tweets")
tweets  = c.fetchall()
print(len(tweets))
```

And when I run my flask application I receive this error:

```
tweets  = c.fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError
```

It should give me a total of **8860871** db lines

When I run with for example:

```
tweets  = c.fetchmany(200000)
```

It works.

An example of single query could be:

```
[(947618506761048064,
  '2018-01-01 00:00:32',
  'Parabéns a esta caganita que diz ser minha prima  @Matilde09159853 http link',
  '{"user": "ericamarcelino1", "place_type": "city", "place_name": "Bombarral, Portugal"}',
  'Bombarral',
  'Leiria',
  'ericamarcelino1')]
```

How can I go through this error and fetch all my data?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, have you tried to check what the db variable returns when trying to create the connection?
I have a guess that maybe your file path might contain many special characters that are not being interpreted as it should and therefore not reading your db file.

Comment: Also, would you please update the post with some example of data inside your db file? So we can figure out the data structure and how to reproduce the scenario

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input, I've updated my problem. I don't think the path is the problem, beaucase when I use "fetchmany(20000)" I can run without any problems.

Comment: I've created a sample database with simple data and your code works. The only change I did was changing from capital letters SELECT and FROM to lower ones.

Comment: The `sqlite3.OperationalError` indicates an issue with the database operation, not necessarily the `sqlite3` package's implementation. Maybe try the sqlite command line interface? https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: I've created a simple .db file with two entries with slqite3 terminal and everything seemed to work fine here.

Comment: Maybe emojis break the retrieval of db data? I don't know how python handles those characters.